# Imageresizer Authentication with Owin

Tags: c#, owin, imageresizer

Im using [Imageresizer 4](http://imageresizing.net/) in a MVC 5 application. We have the need to authenticate the image requests so we are using the following event:

`protected void Application_Start() 
{
    ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeAllImages = true;
    ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage += AuthorizeImage;
}`

The AuthorizeImage method looks like this:

`private static void AuthorizeImage(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlAuthorizationEventArgs e) 
{
    //This line throws an exception if runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is set to false
    var owinContext = context.GetOwinContext();
    Authorize(context, owinContext);
}`

The problem is that we are using Owin so we need the OwinContext from the HttpContext. When calling the `GetOwinContext` method we get the following error:

**No owin.Environment item was found in the context**

If I set the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true in web.config, everything works like it should.

But I don't want to use runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests since it has a performance impact.

My question is: Can I somehow force the Owin middleware to execute before a specific HttpModule?

Something like this(psuedo code):

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" modulesToRunBefore="Owin........" />
</modules>`

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true`, unless you can change how the owin module is registered, and tell *it* to run for all requests.